# How to use React-Scroll to scroll to element on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been trying to use the react-scroll library with my HTML to be able to click on a cube i made up of divs in a wrap, scrolling down to another part of the page.

My react-scroll **code** is this:

```
var React = require('react');
var Scroll = require('react-scroll');

var Link = Scroll.Link;
var Element = Scroll.Element;
var Events = Scroll.Events;
var scroll = Scroll.animateScroll;
var scrollSpy = Scroll.scrollSpy;


var Section = React.createClass({
      componentDidMount: function() {
        scrollToElement(link1); {
          let scroller = Scroll.scroller;
          scroller.scrollTo(link1, {
              duration: 1500,
              delay: 100,
              smooth: true,

            },
          )
        }
      },


    ///

    render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

I'm trying to scroll to this element in my HTML:

```
<Element name="link1">
  <div class="bg2" id="snap1"></div>
</Element>
```

When one of these cubes are clicked:

```
<div class="cube" change-background colorcode=¨#f45642¨>
  <div class="front"><span>Resume</span></div>
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

I made this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zhenkgxz/8/ but I'm new to JSfiddle so Im not sure if I have set it up correctly. Anyways, how can I get the scroll animation on click of the cube?

Comment: your section class is misformatted (brackets not matching) and is missing a render() function

Comment: Fixed my code. I'm confused on how render is used. How can I link a div wrap I already have in my html? @MichaelRitter

Comment: normally, you only have a base html in the actual html file. Everything else is created by React. A root Component is rendered into the main container via ReactDOM.render. that component itself can render other components... until the full page is shown. Thats what render is for. You also set your hooks there (set the onclick-handler of some html-object to trigger a react-function (like your self-defined `scrollToElement` one)

Comment: Yeah.. I was confused on whether all the HTML was rendered by React itself..know I know. Could I just paste my HTML to the render then?@MichaelRitter

Comment: yea for example. i didn't check what your angular stuff does tho (from the fiddle). Just create some div in the body of the html-file and give it a id like "app" or "main". then place everything that should be rendered in there inside your `render()` method of the component and render the component into that div

Comment: how do I link the render() method to the div?@MichaelRitter

Comment: Apparently JS fiddle doesn't want to use the react-scroll library..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134180/discussion-between-michael-ritter-and-feners).